# Update function on select box change

Tags: javascript, ajax, daterangepicker

I have a date range picker that I imports the min and max date from an Ajax call. However I want the Ajax call to update when a different city is selected via the select box. How do I do this? This is my code:

```
function getPricingDateRanges(callback) {
    var city = document.getElementById("pricingcityselect").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getpricingdaterangepicker.php?city=' + city,       // Change this to the uri of your file
        method: 'GET',                 // Use the GET method
        dataType: 'json',              // Expect a JSON response
        success: function(response) {  // What will happen when the request succeeds
            if (response) {            // Check if there is a response
                callback(response);    // Pass the response into the callback
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
getPricingDateRanges(function(dates) {

    $('input[name="pricing_start_date"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            // Here use your dates that you've got from the server.
            var dateRanges = dates;
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end)); 
            }, false);
        }
    });
$('input[name="pricing_start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    document.getElementById("pricing_start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    document.getElementById("pricing_end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
});

$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

and the html:

```
<select id="pricingcityselect" onchange="getPricingDateRanges()">
```

The above does not work because it's a call back, but I am sure you get the idea of what I am trying to do. Help?